# Python - Filter DataFrame by Sub DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I got a DataFrame like this:

```
    A   B   C 
1   1   2   3
2   4   5   6
3   7   8   9
```

And I want to filter it by a sub set of DataFrame:

```
    A   C 
1   4   6
2   7   9
```

Finally, I can get this output:

```
    A   B   C
2   4   5   6 
3   7   8   9
```

How can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [92]: d1.merge(d2)
Out[92]:
   A  B  C
0  4  5  6
1  7  8  9
```